# Is there a way to deselect a vertex while using Poly Build?

Tags: modeling

When I use the Poly Build tool while a vertex is selected I have the following situation:

I want to select a different vertex and currently I have to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Right-click to drag around the new vertex.

Instead of using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is there a way with the poly build tool to deselect the currently selected vertex or vertices?

After this if I want to move a vertex I have to press <kbd>G</kbd> to move and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Right-click etc.

Its a lot of key presses. I don't see any options with the poly build tool to deselect and vertex move.

Comment: Another way to deselect verts is to press C for Circle Select and then press the middle button.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is another option.